# jquery selector - choosing parents but not children

Tags: jquery, selector, parent-child, siblings

I am trying to use jquery to select an element and add a class to that element. My html is similar to the following:

```
<ul id="top">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor">
    <a href="#">Corporate</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11">
                <a href="#">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-88 current_page_item menu-item-90">
                <a href="#">Press</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu"><li><a href="#">Link</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add a class of "arrow" to every anchor link that is a direct child of the first-level `<li>` elements. In other words, I would like the "corporate" link to have a class of "arrow" but not any of the anchor links within .submenu to have that class. I have tried the following jquery (`$("li.current_page_ancestor a:nth-child(1)").addClass("arrow");`), but it adds the class to every anchor link, which makes sense. How do I just add that class to the anchor links that are a direct child of the top-level list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is the child selector:

```
$('li.current_page_ancestor > a').
  add($('.sub-menu').parent().children('a')).
    addClass('arrow');
```

Comment: that worked out well. I also want to add the class of arrows to all anchor links that are inside the parent of .sub-menu. I just updated the above example. In this example, I would want to add the class of arrow to the absolute last anchor link in my code ( the one directly above sub-menu)

Comment: How's that anchor above the sum-menu? It's within it :-/

Comment: @JCHASE I updated my post to reflect the change in your question

Comment: its the nav link that you hover over to get the sub-menu. See demo here: http://cruisinc.eu/management/   The crew link should have an arrow next to it because it has a submenu

Comment: not seeing a difference in your post!! It works great for all of the current pages, but for the nav links that are not current, and also have a set of children (sub menu) it does not work!

Comment: seems silly to add submenu. It is already generated by wordpress. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$('ul#top > li > a').addClass('arrow')
```

The css-selector " > " means "direct decedent", or "direct child".

Comment: You sure it's not just your css that messes things up?

Comment: you are right, thanks! I am also trying to add another class, see my text in comment above.